# how to set multiple JSON request from the file in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I m newbie in JMeter. I am trying to send multiple JSON request using Jmeter where.

1. Login (getToken)
   Request - I m loading a csv file for username and password

   {
       "Username": "${Username}",
       "Password": "${Password}",

   }

Response

```
{"Status":"Success","HttpStatus":200,"Data":{"token_type":"Bearer","token":"eITWDFHzN-awdaJy5SQ","name":"JMeter","u_ID":"6934FF18C130"}}
```

2. AddQuery(Using #1 's response token and another parameter called U_ID )

for this I have request like this

```
 {

"Comment":"TEST COMMENT",
"Type":"TEST",
"DATE":"04-02-2020",   
"ColA":"",
"ColB":"",
"ColC":"",
"ColD":"",
"ColE":"",
 "User":"${name}"
}
```

Here no of columns are diffrent.
So I want to set up a plan where i want to read request JSON from the file. I tried with storing diffrent request in CSV file but JMeter is not able to read it.

I found if you storethe request in CSV file then it is adding extra " " like below.

JMeter request

```
POST data:
""{""Comment"":""TEST COMMENT"""

[no cookies]
```

Which is best way to handle/ ready JSON request from the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) and [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) functions combination directly in "Body Data" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file.json,,)})}
```

[image]

where:

- `__FileToString()` - loads file from disk
- `eval()` - evaluates eventual [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) to resolve their values, i.e. `${name}`

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/)